# cant return right value from powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Help me pls,

i'am going my mind, what is wrong in my script??? i'm testing this script under Windows 2012.

There is shares:

\FS-SHARES\TEST12

\FS-SHARES\TEST15

\FS-SHARES\TEST20

---

```
function StripShare($sharename) {

    $res=$sharename -replace ".*\\(.*)" , '$1'
    return $res

}

function getShareProp($sharename)  {
    $s=""
    Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share -computername "." -filter "Type=0" | % {  
        if (stripshare($_.name) -eq $sharename) { 
            $s=$_.name 
        }
    }

    return $s
}

getShareProp(stripshare("s:\TEST12"))


OUTPUT 
----
TEST20

getShareProp(stripshare("s:\TEST15"))
---
OUTPUT 
TEST20
```

Solved!

p.s. Something strange with pipeline in powershell 3.

```
function getShareProp($sharename)  {
        $s=""
        $a=Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share -computername "." -filter "Type=0" 
        foreach ($_ in $a) {  
            $t=stripshare($_.name)
            if ($t -eq $sharename) { 
                $s=$_.name 
            }
        }

        return $s
}
```

Comment: You should post the solution as an [answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are attempting to accomplish, but I think just adding to the filter will mostly provide the same functionality.

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share -computername "." -filter "Type=0 and name='TEST12'" | select Name
```

or if you're looking for the Share name associated with a physical path.

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share -computername "." -filter "Type=0 and path='S:\TEST12'" | select Name
```